# How to stop C# code from waiting until a excel macro is finished

Tags: c#, vba

I run a excel macro from c# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, however the C# code is paused until the long excel macro is finished. I want to run both at once. How to do this?

Comment: take a look at [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run your code in separate thread, the easiest way to accomplish that is using standard .Net Task library this way :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Do something here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use treading, have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/